# WordPress upload file

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I would like to upload a file like as (.apk) but I can't. I receive this message.
Sorry, this file type is not allowed for security reasons.

I show solutions as to settings on multisite, but I don't have this choice on my version. In which way I could enable the settings of multisite?

Is there any way to upload files like apk,( may a plugin)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your functions.php file and add the following code inside it.

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'allow_custom_mimes');

function allow_custom_mimes ( $existing_mimes = array() ) {
  // with mime type ‘application/vnd.android.package-archive
  $existing_mimes['apk'] = 'application/vnd.android.package-archive';
  return $existing_mimes;
}
```

Restart your server after adding code and check.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I find the file functions.php but because I am not so familiar I need a little bit more help.

How can I reset the server? I visit the site with admin rights? Could do it myself or need to address at my "host company"?

Comment: @EleniAgou  You do not need to restart your server. Also, I edited the code to remove the fancy quotes since that would break the site.